# Android Appium: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: java, eclipse, appium, appium-android

I am testing an app using Eclipse + Appium + UiAutomator2 + AndroidDriver + Testng.

When I run this specific test I get this error:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started

This only happens when I give a Thread.Sleep about 120 seconds.

I have to do that, I have to stay in that screen for about 120 whithout any interaction.

If I comment the step before the thread.sleep (including the thread.sleep), the test runs normally.

I want to run this test case successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In your test case add "**newCommandTimeout**" in your desired capability

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);
```

> newCommandTimeout : How long (in seconds) Appium will wait for a new
> command from the client before assuming the client quit and ending the
> session